# Why my variable corrupted (Run-Time Check Failure) after exit program when using string parameter in functions

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-2015, parameters, runtime-error

I am trying to use string parameter passing from func1 to func2.

All the messages displayed in correct order, but after I exited the program, Visual Studio 2015 showed me a warning:

***Run-Time Check Failure # 2 - Stack around the variable 'y' was corrupted***

Below is my codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning (disable:4996)

//Functions declaration
int func1(char x[], char y[]);
int func2(char x[], char y[]);

void main() {
    char x[25], y[25];

    strcpy(x, "x-coordinate");
    strcpy(y, "y-coordinate");

    printf("Passing 'x' and 'y' strings to func1()");
    func1(x, y);

    system("pause");

}

int func1(char x[], char y[]){
    strcpy(x, "x-coordinate received by func1()");
    strcpy(y, "y-coordinate received by func1()");

    printf("\n%s", x);
    printf("\n%s", y);

    printf("\n\nPassing 'x' and 'y' strings to func2()");
    func2(x, y);
}

int func2(char x[], char y[]) {
    strcpy(x, "x-coordinate received by func2()");
    strcpy(y, "y-coordinate received by func2()");

    printf("\n%s", x);
    printf("\n%s", y);
    printf("\n");
}
```

What mistake I made?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You write out of bounds of the arrays you have. That leads to *undefined behavior* which makes your program *ill-formed* and invalid. End of story.

Comment: "x-coordinate received by func1()" is more than 25 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` and `y` are arrays of size 25 and you copy strings of larger size into them in here:

```
strcpy(x, "x-coordinate received by func1()");
strcpy(y, "y-coordinate received by func1()");
```

and here:

```
strcpy(x, "x-coordinate received by func2()");
strcpy(y, "y-coordinate received by func2()");
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you use the values after `strcpy` only to `printf`. You don't need to assign the strings you want to print to a variable (x nor y).

You can do:

```
printf("\n x-coordinate received by func1()");
```

If you do it like this, you save yourself some `strcpy` (they take time O(n) where n is the length of the string)

Comment: Ya, I don't know why I could write such ineffective codes. Thank you for correcting me. :)